# Jmeter response - org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: example.com:443 failed to respond

Tags: jmeter

Created a test with the login requests and after some time it stops working. Login request is failed with

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: example.com:443 failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:939)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:650)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1301)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1290)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

**Request details:**

*Request:*

```
POST https://example.com/auth/token
POST data:
{"scope":"application","grant_type":"sso_token"}
[no cookies]
```

[image]

*Request's headers:*

```
Connection: keep-alive
authority: example.com
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ii1LSTNROW5OUjdiUm9meG1lWm9YcWJIWkdldyJ9.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.V-h8D1TGj9vb2jVwBFGtm3jBH54lfGMOD_xHWYbfornN5ml31K6FnIumMU5i2oBOUcMpDOgM-2_XCbnWPou5iCc_I703kd_zwW6CAgUDBVJtfSmU6Go--hohzMWZuFG7ftKIX0_ftDmRzqJWOw-bwKy5E4NdXImibeKgQsx_N4QFLMx6X9SVDYhf5mXnabkgpdgEn8m2BtM__mYlCJgw7ci6WRuEg6CzocsrKJrNsiUF74vPLkp-tDkbXZFY-1PvNAzAPQEVUZ2kzIXKDf8_O2vd0ozycaz-MVKw6nxOZnYNzXVaTBvkw9sIFMWbW4biZw7GxgrIIC1ux4KvpXuwA
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: application/json
origin: https://example.com_2.net
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/18.0.2.1)
```

[image]

The Bearer is taken from the previous request which works fine, however it's related to the different authorization system. The process is the following - In the Transaction controller I have get Bearer request from one system and with the Bearer authorize in other service.
If I add all information from the request to the Postmen - everything is fine. That's why I assume the problem on the Jmeter side. I tried different clients implementations in the HTTP Advanced tab sampler, reinstalled Java machine.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "after some time"?

The error is pretty clear: the host you're trying to test doesn't repond. JMeter sends a HTTP Request and waits for the response and the response.

If the issue is happening under the particular load and cannot be reproduced at lower loads - it clearly indicates the system under test [bottleneck](https://www.educative.io/blog/performance-testing-101-bottlenecks) and you need to analyze what is the root cause by

- checking baseline operating system health metrics like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk usage, etc. It can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)
- check application and operating system logs on the system under test side
- re-run your test with [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) telemetry enabled, it will allow you to see what exactly causes the failure

If you cannot successfully execute request even with 1 user in JMeter and can do this in Postman most probably there is a network connectivity issue, like you're behind a [corporate proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) which is being detected automatically by Postman. JMeter cannot auto-detect proxies and you need to [explicitly set the details via command-line arguments or system properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server).

Comment: Everything was fine and last week on Thursday it stopped working. It's not under load - only 1 request. I tried on different machine and on that machine the same works fine while on the machine which I use for the test execution it doesn't.

Comment: About the corporate proxy - the postman works from the same machine when Jmeter doesn't